# Matching free terms in a polynom with real coefficients using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to make an assignment for Programming Techniques and I have struggled to match the free terms in a polynomial, (2.0x^2+3.5x-**3.0** or 45x+**2**), which is given as a string. I have tried to use the following regex:

```
(-{0,1}\d+(\.\d+){0,1})(?![0-9]\.*x\^\d))
```

I know the way the way I approached it might not be too good, but I did not have too much time for understanding regex in a more complex way, only slightly, and I got stuck at the point in which I would like to get only the numbers like with the format: ***±# or ±#.#*** which are not followed by: ***x or x^#*** where ***#*** represents one or more digits.

Comment: Is it always the last term? Because that would make things much easier.

Comment: No, actually it can be anywhere in the polynomial, I forgot to mention that..

Comment: What language is this regex used in? The environment makes a difference with regex.

Comment: The regex is used in Java, and for testing I have used this site: https://regexr.com/4amm9, and for other patterns it had worked fine

Comment: Are you asked to solve the whole thing in regex, or can you use a bit of Java plumbing? Because `(?<!\^)[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$|[-+])` works, but I doubt that's what you're asked for

Comment: A more reasonable solution IMO would be to capture an optional variable while you match terms and check in Java whether there was a captured variable, returning the only match which has none.

Comment: I have seen the negative lookbehind feature, but I could not test it to see if it would help because it was not supported on the sites with regex testers, and so I did not tried to use it in Java.

Comment: @ManuelMaior I've included both options in my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full regex solution :

```
(?<!\^)[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$|[-+])
```

- `(?<!\^)` won't match if the previous character is a `^`
- `[-+]?` will match an optional sign character
- `\d+(\.\d+)?` will match the number which is composed of an integer part followed by an optional floating part
- `(?=$|[-+])` won't match unless what follows is a sign character or the end of the string

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/1rofFK/1).

---

Java solution with term-matching :

```
Pattern termPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(x(?:\\^\\d+)?)?");
Matcher termMatcher = termPattern.matcher(input);
while (termMatcher.find()) {
    if (termMatcher.group(1) == null) {
        // you have a free term
    }
}
```

The regex matches an integer part followed by an optional floating part then an optional `x^n` part which is captured in a capturing group. A `Matcher` is created from applying the pattern to the input. Calling `Matcher.find` allows us to iterate over the multiple matches on the input string. For each match we check the content of the first capturing group, when it's null we have a free term.

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/VhYP9w).

---

Yet anoter solution would be to simply split the string around `[+-]` and for each part test whether it contains `x` or not.

Comment: Yes, finally I have tested the solution you have given and it seems to work good. Also thank you for explaining each part in the solution. It is really clear now.

Comment: @ManuelMaior you're welcome ! Note that lookarounds (positive/negative lookafter/lookbehind) are an advanced feature of regex which you usually don't learn right away, so if you haven't explored regexs that much I think your teacher would rather expect something like the second solution.

Comment: Yes, the second solution might seem more simple and it also has a good logic.

Comment: I've edited the second regex to make the exponent part of `x^n` optional. This doesn't change your result since you don't care about the results with an `x^n` part for now, but if you're made to capture every term it is necessary (so would matching terms without coefficient such as the lone `x` in your sample input, but I'll leave that part to you)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it: `(?<!\^)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?![x.\d])`

```
(?<!     | Negative lookbehind:
  \^     |   A literal "^"
)        | Close group
(        | Capture the following:
  \d+    |   Match one or more digits
  (?:    |   Match the following group:
    \.   |     A literal "."
    \d+  |     One or more digits
  )?     |   Close group, optional match
)        | End capture
(?!      | Negative lookahead:
  [x.\d] |   Either an "x", ".", or any digit
)        | Close group
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/S94Qn6/5)

---

```
String s = "5x-50.1+x^2-2+20x";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\^)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?![x.\\d])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // Output: 50.1
}
```

Comment: thank you for this alternative solution and for the explainations!